# Syncfusion RibbonWindow Icon does not appear in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, syncfusion

I have been trying to set an Icon that appears on the top left of my RibbonWindow but I cannot.

My problem is that when I use a transparent icon, it is displayed perfectly on the taskbar but it does not appear on the top left of the window.

I have tried both png and ico just in case but it did not make any difference. If the image is not transparent though it appears in both places but with a white background on the taskbar (which is what I am trying to get rid of in the first place).

I am using Syncfusion Essential Studio WPF 13.1.0.21

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

In RibbonWindow have a “Office2010Icon” property, this property is used to set icon on the top left of RibbonWindow. We have prepared sample for the same. Please download the sample from the below link.

Sample link: [RibbonWindowSample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/167851/ze/RibbonWindowSample2046438751.zip)

Regards,

Mariappan S